# How to import a .tsv file

Tags: r, import, read.table, readr

I need to read a table that is a `.tsv` file in R.

[image]

```
test <- read.table(file='drug_info.tsv')
# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#   line 1 did not have 10 elements
test <- read.table(file='drug_info.tsv', )
# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#   line 1 did not have 10 elements
scan("drug_info.tsv")
# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#   scan() expected 'a real', got 'ChallengeName'
scan(file = "drug_info.tsv")
# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
#   scan() expected 'a real', got 'ChallengeName'
```

How should I read it?

Comment: Please copy/paste the first 5 rows of the file into your question and remove the picture.

Comment: pretty much `read.delim` with the default settings

Comment: `read.table` default to using a whitespace delimited (meaning space or tab generally). If you have spaces, you can explicitly set the delimiter as tab with `sep="\t"`. `read.table` works with valid input files, so if there is a problem importing your data, it's with the file, and not the function. So in order to help you, we'd need you to share a sample of the file you are actually trying to import, not a picture of the data in some other program.

Answer (score 45):

This should do it:

```
read.table(file = 'drug_info.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: That should give the same error as reported, line 1 does not have sufficient elements

Comment: I think the down-vote came a bit prematurely here, as we don't have any actual data to test with any method yet.

Answer (score 16):

Using fread from the package data.table will read the data and will skip the error you are getting using read.table.

```
require(data.table)

data<-as.data.frame(fread("drug_info.tsv"))
```

Comment: Thumbs up for this solution as it can handle large data table avoiding session time out on the ShinyUI webpage

Answer (score 14):

You can treat the data like a csv, and specify tab delimination.

```
read.csv("drug_info.tsv", sep = "\t")
```

Answer (score 6):

`utils::read.delim()` is most commonly used in such case if you don't want to install other library. The sample code could be something like:

```
test <- read.delim(file='drug_info.tsv')
```

or much more friendly io functions could be available from [`readr library`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/), where a [`read_tsv` named function](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) is available directly:

```r
test <- readr::read_tsv('drug_info.tsv')
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that only the first line does not have the right number of elements, and that this is the column names line. Skip the first line:

```
 d <- read.table('drug_info.tsv', skip=1)
```

Now read it

```
 first <- readLines('drug_info.tsv', n=1)
```

Inspect it, fix it such that its number of elements matches `d` and then

```
 colnames(d) <- first
```

If that does not work, you can do

```
 x <- readLines('drug_info.tsv')
```

and diagnostics like this:

```
 sapply(x, length)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to include fill = TRUE.

```
test <- read.table(file='drug_info.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```